# iptables log url query string

Tags: iptables, logging, url, querystring

I log and drop packets send to specific IP/domain name. I would like to be able to log url parameters for these dropped packet.

This is an example url:

```
http://somedomain.com/test.php?param1=test1&param2=test2
```

This is what i'm doing e.g:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d somedomain.com --dport 80 -m string --string 'param1=' --algo bm -j LOGGING
```

In LOGGING chain:

```
iptables -A LOGGING -j LOG --log-prefix "somedomain.com Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
```

I tried these options without any success:

```
--log-ip-options
--log-tcp-options
```

Basically, i'd like to be able to get same relevant info as from `tcpdump` but because i drop packets, you know the story, i cannot use tcpdump here (as i understand it)...

Is it possible using iptables log (to a text file?!) to get URL query string of dropped packet? In this example, it would be:

```
param1=test1&param2=test2
```

My knwoledge about all of this is near the zero so excuse me if it's a silly question.

Thx

Comment: URLs are not on IP/TCP level. You would need a plugin which can assemble and log application level content. (Some NIDS can do that with diverted packages from NF). When you drop sun packets for new connections you will never see the URL containing packets anyway. But generally you can also write the dropped packages to a user mode queue for logging. ULOGD can write them in pcap format: http://www.stearns.org/doc/iptables-ulog.v0.1.html

Comment: @eckes I heard before about ulog, i will look at it. But would it be possible to get the output (only GET query in my case) in text format?

Comment: Unlikely (for the reasons mentioned above)

Comment: @eckes Ok i guess i better understand what you meant. Thank you

Comment: What is serving these urls?  nginx, apache, haproxy, other?  Is TLS being used?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to achieve that correctly with iptables alone, if only for the fact that the request URL might be fragmented across several packets.

Since you are filtering on OUTPUT, probably a more robust and easier way would be to install a local HTTP proxy, such as [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), and add your filtering rules to squid.

For the sake of completeness, you can then use iptables to block everything but the squid proxy to connect to this forbidden host.

---

According to the following [Config example](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/AtSource), you should have in your `squid.conf`

```
http_port 3129 intercept
```

and then intercept requests with

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d somedomain.com --dport 80 -m owner  --uid-owner squid -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d somedomain.com --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3129
```

The first rule is required so that squid itself can proxy the request to the original host, if you want to let some through.

You can observe the URLs of the requests by consulting the default `access.log` file produced by squid. For actually blocking URLs you should setup some ACLs in `squid.conf`:

```
acl blocktestphp url_regex test.php
http_access deny blocktestphp
```